# Prolog text game printing descriptions duplicate output

Tags: prolog

I'm working on a text based adventure game in prolog. I'm trying to define something that prints out all the adjacent rooms and their descriptions, except when I try to use it it is printing duplicate items and their descriptions.

The definitions for adjacent_rooms is as follows:

```
adjacent_rooms(Location):-
    is_connected(Location, AdjacentLocation),
    name(AdjacentLocation, AdjacentName),
    short_desc(AdjacentLocation, AdjacentDescription),
    write(AdjacentName), write(': '), write(AdjacentDescription),nl,fail.
adjacent_rooms(_).
```

Below is the output when I call adjacent_rooms(bedroom).

```
?- adjacent_rooms(bedroom).
Your Bedroom's Closet: A cozy little room used for storing your valuables
Your Bedroom's Closet: 
: A cozy little room used for storing your valuables
: 
Hallway: Long pathway that has pictures hanging on wall
Hallway: 
: Long pathway that has pictures hanging on wall
```

What is causing duplicate names and descriptions to be printed? Thanks.

Comment: Not related to the question but your second clause should be  `adjacent_rooms(_).` so that calls to the predicate (which implements a failure-driven loop) succeed.

Comment: Prolog will backtrack on the `fail`. So it depends upon how your `short_description`, `name`, and `is_connected` are defined and how they behave on backtracking in this case.